# I get an error when trying to upload a file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, gridfs

I'm using skipper gridfs to upload a picture in my sails app,here is my function:

```
upload: (req, res) => {
        req.file('avatar')
            .upload({
                adapter: require('skipper-gridfs'),
                uri: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/27017/linucLab',
                maxBytes: 1000000

            }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
                if (err) return res.serverError(err);
                else return res.json({
                    files: uploadedFiles,
                    textParams: req.allParams()
                });
            });

    }
```

I get this error

```
MongoError: Can't get executor for query { files_id: ObjectId('591b702ad01d3aa826d545ba'), n: { $gte: 0 } }
```

Comment: You can use expressfileupload package for easy uploading a file.

Comment: What version of mongo are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mongo 3.4.0

Comment: Looks like that URL should probably be `'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/linucLab'` (note the `:` before `27017`).

Comment: I'm having the same error, figured a way to solve it ? if so might as well share the solution please